# Cramér-Rao / Wolfowitz bound with nuisance parameter

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, fisher-information, point-estimation, cramer-rao

Let $F$ be a distribution with two parameters, $\theta$ and $\phi$, whose values are non-random but unknown. Consider a sampling procedure in which $N$ samples $x_1, \ldots x_N$ are obtained from i.i.d. realizations of the distribution $F$. The sample size $N$ can be fixed, or can be randomly given by a sequential sampling procedure, with $N$ determined by the sequence of observed outcomes $x_1, x_2, \ldots$.

Consider the task of estimating $\theta$ from $x_1, \ldots, x_N$. The parameter $\phi$ is a nuisance parameter, i.e. its value is of no interest. Let $\hat \theta$ be an estimation of $\theta$ computed from $x_1, \ldots, x_N$.

I am trying to find a Cramér-Rao-type bound for the variance of $\hat \theta$. If it were not for the nuisance parameter $\phi$, the answer would be the [Cramer-Rao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound) bound for $N$ fixed, or [Wolfowitz](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-18/issue-2/The-Efficiency-of-Sequential-Estimates-and-Walds-Equation-for-Sequential/10.1214/aoms/1177730439.full)'s generalization for the sequential case, subject to suitable regularity conditions.

Are there equivalent bounds in the presence of the nuisance parameter? The papers by [Bhapkar](https://www.ism.ac.jp/editsec/aism/pdf/046_3_0593.pdf) (1994) and [Godambe](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2336575) (1984) seem to be related to this, but I am afraid I cannot make much sense of them.

I am mostly interested in the sequential case, but a result for fixed $N$ would be useful too. Similarly, I am interested in the general case when $\hat \theta$ is not restricted to be unbiased, but a result for the unbiased case would be useful. The parameters $\theta$ and $\phi$ are both one-dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer, for the case with $N$ fixed, using Patrick Breheny's notes on Likelihood Theory, in particular the lecture on [efficiency](https://myweb.uiowa.edu/pbreheny/7110/f23/notes/10-23.pdf). Thanks to [@user1848065](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/311086/user1848065), who pointed me to those notes in a [comment to another question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/641412/sufficient-conditions-for-asymptotic-efficiency-of-mle#comment1198438_641412).

The key is to use the *vector form* of the Cramér-Rao bound. Let $\mathrm{\mathbf I}$ denote the $2 \times 2$ information matrix for the vector of parameters $\theta$, $\phi$ in that order, and let $\mathrm{\mathbf J} = \mathrm{\mathbf I}^{-1}$.

Then,

- The Cramér-Rao bound for an unbiased estimator of $\theta$ when $\phi$ is *unknown* is $J_{1,1}$. This applies regardless of wheter $\phi$ is considered as a "nuisance" or a "wanted" parameter. In other words, the fact that we do not want to *estimate* $\phi$ cannot be exploited to improve the estimation of $\theta$.
- The Cramér-Rao bound for an unbiased estimator of $\theta$ when $\phi$ is a *known* number is $1/I_{1,1}$, which is less than or equal to $J_{1,1}$. In other words, knowledge of the *true* value of $\phi$ is in general helpful for estimating $\theta$.