# Sufficient conditions for asymptotic efficiency of MLE

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, estimators, asymptotics, efficiency

Maximum-likelihood estimators are, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation#Properties), asymptotically efficient, that is they achieve the Cramér-Rao bound when sample size tends to infinity. But this seems to require some regularity conditions.

Can you give, or point me to, a set of conditions that ensure that the maximum-likelihood estimator is asymptotically efficient? Are there different sets of conditions for this? Do the conditions change depending in whether the parameter to be estimated is scalar or multi-dimensional?

Comment: I think these set of notes do list the conditions needed to establish the asymptotic efficiency of the MLE : https://myweb.uiowa.edu/pbreheny/7110/f23/notes.html.

Comment: The results there are quite restrictive. For M-estimators (which the MLE is) you can get asymptotic normality under a variety of conditions. I would recommend VanderVaart Chapter 5 (https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/asymptotic-statistics/mand-zestimators/1C38BDDC13F347DF59FF5118396C3D1C) for a list of many of the most useful results to get Asymptotic Normality of the MLE (user1848065's conditions are contained in section 5.6, classical conditions). Would be happy to expand on a full answer if these are a bit inscrutable!

Comment: @PhysicsKid Thank you so much for the reference. These are the types of results I am looking for. However, I am interested in asymptotic efficiency (i.e. degree of asymptotic "closeness" to the Cramér-Rao bound), rather than normality. How is the latter related to the former?

Answer (score 2):

A fundamental condition for MLE-efficiency is correct specification. So this is *not* quasi-MLE territory.

1. Denote $s$ to be the score of the likelihood, and $H$ to be its Hessian.
2. The variance of MLE is, to begin with,
   $$V_{MLE} = \big[-E(H)\big]^{-1}\big[E(ss')\big]\big[-E(H)\big]^{-1}. \tag{1}$$

2. But under correct specification (and some regularity conditions on the density) the **Information Equality** holds and we have
   $$\big[-E(H)\big]^{-1} = \big[E(ss')\big] \tag{2}$$

3. It follows that the variance of the MLE becomes
   $$V_{MLE} = -\big[E(H)\big]^{-1} \tag{3}$$
4. But the RHS of $(3)$ is the Cramer-Rao bound for unbiased (or asymptotically unbiased) estimators. So MLE attains the Cramer-Rao bound.

See **Amemiya, T. (1985). *Advanced econometrics*.** Harvard University Press.
ch. 1.3.2 and 4.2.4

Also, **Lehmann, E. L.; Casella, G. (1998). *Theory of Point Estimation (2nd ed.)***. Springer. p. 115 leading to Lemma 5.3 that is in page 116.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I'm missing something, as I don't see how this answers my question. You conclude that "under some regularity conditions [...] the MLE attains the Cramer-Rao bound". But my question was: what are those conditions? Also, what do you mean by "correct specification"?

Comment: @LuisMendo I gave you the references to lookup these regularity conditions. Correct specification means that the density on which we base the likelihood and ML estimation is indeed the density characterizing our sample.